# Why would a django UpdateView return a 404 until the server was restarted?

Tags: python, django

I have the following create and update views (django 1.5, Python 2.7):

```
class NewsCreateView(
        PermissionRequiredMixin,
        CreateView
    ):
    model = News
    template_name_suffix = "_create_form"
    form_class = NewsForm
    login_url = "/login/"
    permission_required = "news.add_news"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation to get a context
        context = super(NewsCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = News.tags.all()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit = False)
        obj.slug = slugify(obj.headline)
        obj.writer = self.request.user.person
        obj.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        obj.featured = False
        obj.enable_comments = True
        return super(NewsCreateView, self).form_valid(form)


class NewsUpdateView(
        PermissionRequiredMixin,
        UpdateView
    ):
    model = News
    template_name_suffix = "_update_form"
    form_class = NewsForm
    login_url = "/login/"
    permission_required = "news.change_news"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation to get a context
        context = super(NewsUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = News.tags.all()
        return context
```

The `CreateView` behaves as expected, as does the `UpdateView` *in development only*. In production, however, the `UpdateView` returns a 404 for any news article created since the last Gunicorn restart. Restarting Gunicorn makes all `UpdateView` pages work fine.

I can't get much useful debugging information because I can't recreate the bug in my development environment. Does anyone know what's going on here?

UPDATE
As requested, here are the Managers at work on this model. From `models.py`

```
# visibility
all_news =  models.Manager()
objects = LiveNewsManager()
```

and from `managers.py`

```
class LiveNewsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(LiveNewsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(status = self.model.LIVE_STATUS).filter(pub_date__lt = timezone.now())
```

Comment: Can you show us your News model manager `tags`?

Comment: That's just plain [`django-taggit`](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: What about the default News model manager?

Comment: Added now. I hadn't thought of that as a potential source of the problem so I'll start looking there. The Manager's purpose is to let people submit articles without them going live or appearing in Haystack search results.

Comment: That looks OK to me - I assumed you'd be doing some time filtering, and was wondering if the time you used as "now" was calculated somewhere once and cached, but it doesn't look like that's the problem.